# Headers and client library minor version mismatch. how to stop from logging errors or fix?

Tags: php, mysql

So I've just upgraded mysql from 5.5 to 5.6 but have kept the current php version of 5.3.27. After the upgrade I keep getting the error:

PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() function.mysql-connect function.mysql-connect Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50536 Library:50616

Site still works fine no problems but a ton of error logs are being generated how do I turn of the error from being logged.

Or what is the safest way to fix this without causing problems. Without having to rewrite all code. Currently I have to stick with 5.3.27 as if I was to upgrade I would have to change a lot of stuff therefore upgrading php in not a option.

Is there a way to turn off this specific error from logging?

Comment: Is switching from libmysql to [mysqlnd](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) an option? Exactly what is the host system?

Comment: depends if just installing mysqln is all thats needed or would I need recode things? what would it affect?

Comment: Currently the mysql extensions use libmysql to actually "talk" with the mysql server. Mysqlnd is "just" another connector and it's the default for more recent versions of php. Chances are nothing at all will change for your php scripts (though e.g. mysqlnd being subject to php's memory management could hit the memory limit where libmysql did not) - you have to test it anyway, no matter what you're going to change. But if pressed I'd start with switching to mysqlnd. Whether that's an easy option depends on the host system. Could be as easy as `yum install php5-mysqlnd`, could be a nightmare ;-)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :) well the only reason I've upgraded mysql was thinking it might improve my cpu usage. Last few days I've been using 100% constantly changed all tables to use innodb instead of myisam slight change but nothing major still had issues. Now the error_logs are filling up 1mb a minute. At this point really need a fix. Any chance of just getting the error log to stop generating for this specific error? Otherwise I'm going to have to do the above you suggested.

Comment: You could turn off the error_reporting, but then you lose virtually all notices/warning/error messages. You could also keep the old libmysql.so and change the search order so that php will "find" this shared library. But on top of being relatively easy mysqlnd also brings you some performance gain - though looking through the queries and making sure that indices are in place and the scripts really do good _relational_ queries is usually much more fruitful.

Comment: if there is a way to silence/stop this notice only that will be very handy otherwise I think I will just have to wait and find another solution for this problem or hire someone to fix it for me. Thanks again

Comment: see [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). But I urge you to tackle with reason, not just the symptoms. You already took your chances with upgrading mysql and there's a good reason for that warning. So, apply the same safety mechanisms ( test server, backup, ...) as you did when upgrading mysql and just try mysqlnd if possible (you still didn't say what the host os is, so I can't tell you whether it's easy or not).

Comment: I'm on cent os 64. Running a vds. The thing is site is live and has a good amount of users online so cant afford to mess it up go offline and lose my rankings etc.